# Free network monitor on Windows - monitoring windows services

Tags: windows, tomcat, networking, monitoring

I would like to know if exists some sort of software which can:

- monitor the state (stopped, running, etc) of windows services (usually Tomcat) of several servers at the same time
- those servers can be both on our internal network (few) or remote (we reach them though a vpn in this last case)
- must be able to restart the chosen windows service in case they are stopped and send notification via mail (at least)
- must be free (not mandatory)
- must run under windows
- a dashboard with the health state of the network would be a good addition

For the internal network I found the software **Total network monitor** (http://www.softinventive.com/products/total-network-monitor/) to be enough for our needs.
But it's not enough to monitor several remote servers at the same time **each one reachable through a different vpn connection**, so I guess we need some sort of software who can install an agent on each of the remote servers so that they can report back the state of the machine.

Searching online the only option I found seems to be **Spiceworks** (http://www.spiceworks.com/free-network-monitoring-management-software/) which I am having some issues in installing.

What is the best option for our needs?

Thanks

Comment: Do you think this is a better fit in Server Fault?